# socket.send() is raising AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python-2.7, python-sockets

I was developing a program that individual elements from the list to another machine (sender-server,reciever-client). I am sharing my program below

-------------------------client.py------------------------

```
import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 4444                # Reserve a port for your service.

s.connect((host, port))
s.send("Hi server1")

while True:

a=int(s.recv(1024))
tmp=0
while tmp<=a:
    print s.recv(1024)
    tmp=tmp+1
```

----------------------------------server.py------------------------------

```
import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 4444                # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port
s.listen(5)
print "Server listening"
while True:
    c=s.accept()
    b=['a','b']
    d=len(b)
    a=str(d)
    c.send(a)
    for i in range(0,len(b)):
        tmp=str(b[i])
        c.send(tmp)
```

When I run both server and client, the server raises this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 14, in <module>
    c.send(a)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Comment: your client code is not properly indented at `a=int(s.recv(1024))`

Answer (score 4):

1. You'll have to fix the indentation on line 11 of `client.py`.
2. [socket.accept()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.accept) returns a tuple `(conn, addr)` where `conn` is a `socket` object. You have to use that object in line 14 to send things. What you're doing is calling `send()` from the entire tuple which has no method named `send` and so the `AttributeError` gets raised. I'd suggest changing line 11 to `c = s.accept()[0]`.

Comment: Hi @Priyansh , your steps seem to work. The output produced in the client are the characters `a` and `b` in two separate lines. Isn't this line `s.send("Hi server1")` supposed to send a message "Hi server1" to the server as well?
I'm not sure what the OP wants, but your code works 100%.

Comment: Hey @code_byter, that line is definitely sending the message. The problem is that OP is not printing whatever the server receives. Just add this "print c.recv(1024)" after "c=s.accept()[0]" and you'll see that message.